# is there any language that supports automatic evaluation of input expressions?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a language that supports automatic-evaluation.
(not sure this is the right term. so let me describe what I mean below)

For example, a program asks for an `int` as its input, one can give it `2 + 2`, which evaluates to an `int` with value `4`.

Of course, one can certainly make a program that accepts this using any language, but I'm wondering if there is any language that natively supports this.

What are the plus and down sides of this?

P.S: My "ultimate" goal is to decide whether to do this in a language that I'm designing. So I'd appreciate any input especially with regard to design.

Comment: It is often more a library feature than a language one. However, look inside  [Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/). It probably fits the bill (with a different syntax). Also, consider embedding a scripting language (like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) or others) inside your application! Read about [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) and [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: What you're asking - particularly the part where `2 + 2` is evaluated - amounts to executing arbitrary code from an unknown source, which is always a bad idea. For whatever it's worth, Emacs Lisp gets you halfway there, in the sense that it has built-in support for prompting the user for the arguments to interactive functions.

Comment: How is this feature different from a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) ?  Languages that have a REPL include Lisp, Python, Scala, Haskell, Clojure and OCaml.

Comment: @logc: I'm pretty sure REPL is an app, rather than a language.

Comment: In retrospect, this would be safe if your language is purely functional and there's absolutely no backdoors, such that an expression of type `int` can never perform `I/O`, spawn processes, mutate a variable, etc.

Comment: Not sure why my question is closed. Any explanation please?

Comment: @Doval Ah, I hear you, but there are expressions that are not purely functional but are absolutely safe. `now()` (or whatever function that returns the current time) is NOT purely functional because it depends on its environment (ie., timezone), but I'm pretty sure it's "safe"

Comment: A REPL is a language shell.  If you are looking for a language that evaluates any input, then you want to write a shell.

Comment: @OneTwoThree Of course. But creating a secure whitelist of safe functions is a heck of a lot harder and riskier than simply forbidding side effects altogether. All it takes is one oversight for your evaluator to be a gaping security hole.

Comment: Apple's new Swift language supports this (in swift playgrounds), and @Doval makes a good point: the release notes for Swift clearly point out that it is not currently sandboxed and you should be very careful before opening playgrounds from other people.

Comment: Specifying the variables are for precision and security of codes.
You need to define lots of term for automatic evaluating of variables. But a number is not always *int* sometimes it s should use as string, char or another type of numeric variables.

Answer (score 4):

Python2 does it automatically:

```
>>> x = input()
2 + 2
>>> print x
4
```

It was removed in Python3, because it's a misfeature. Evaluating user input without the programmer specifically requesting it is a serious security breach, because the programmer might use it to automatically convert numeric input to numbers, but it lets the user run any Python command, and many python programmers won't even notice this when they use `input()`, because they test it with either numbers(which get converted correctly) or random strings(which crash like they should) and not with actual Python commands.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "any language", the answer is yes. However, I think what you're actually asking is if there's any popular, modern, language, in which case the answer is "maybe".

One language that definitely evaluates expressions when read from the user is Sinclair Basic (at least in its ZX-81 variant), where a numeric input (like, say, `100 INPUT X`) would take something like "2+2" and stuff 4 into the variable X. It also allows you to refer to variables, so you can say "10+A" and it would fetch the value of A and add 10 to it.

When it comes to modern languages, I don't know of any that will do it without at least wrapping the moral equivalent of eval around the resulting input, but in some cases you can do read-time computations via other routes.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is the easy answer

eval('2+2')=4

Now the problem with any language that will do this is how much control do you give the user.  What methods can and can't be called.  In JavaScript when you run Eval you can do anything the Lagrange can.  (not like there is any JS security on the web, but in other builds of JS there could be)